# R Error: Cannot read in xls spreadsheet in R, gives "Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument"

Tags: r, excel, perl

I'm trying to do an exercise from the Doing Data Science book, and at this code I keep erroring out.

```
mt <- read.xls("rollingsales_manhattan.xls", perl="C:\\Perl64\\bin\\perl.exe", pattern="BOROUGH",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

With this error...

```
Error in xls2sep(xls, sheet, verbose = verbose, ..., method = method,  : 
  Intermediate file 'C:\Users\carson\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMjMWfI\file267c48c84956.csv' missing!
Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument
```

I've added that perl value to my method call, to specify where the Perl interpreter is on my machine. I've made sure the working directory is correct and the file name is correct...doing the following command to verify...

```
> list.files()
 [1] "Capture.PNG"                        "dds_ch2_rollingsales"              
 [3] "gross_sqft_vs_price.png"            "gross_sqft_vs_price_with_trend.png"
 [5] "load_cleandata.r"                   "model1 vs index.png"               
 [7] "model2 vs index.png"                "model2a vs index.png"              
 [9] "model3 vs index.png"                "model4 vs index.png"               
[11] "rollingsales_manhattan.xls"
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting R studio from scratch fixed the issue.